# how to filter between dates in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search

I am very new to MVC and software development, and I want to implement a search by date functionality within my application. On the index view I want users to be able to search by two date fields that are available on the web page, "Date" and "Order Date". Currently this is the code I have in the view, it basically specifies the layout of the page.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index","PurchaseOrder",FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Search by Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.TextBox("searchBy","dateSearchBegin") to: @Html.TextBox("searchBy","dateSearchEnd")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /> <br /><br />
        Search by Order Date: &nbsp;@Html.TextBox("searchBy","dateOrderedBegin") to: @Html.TextBox("searchBy","dateOrderedEnd")
        <input type="submit"  value="Search" />
        <br /> <br />
        Search by: @Html.RadioButton("searchBy","Requestor", true) Requestor
        @Html.RadioButton("searchBy","Vendor") Vendor
        @Html.RadioButton("searchBy","workOrder") Work Order # <br />
        @Html.TextBox("search","", new { style = "width:10000px" })
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
    </p>

}
```

In the controller, I have this code. This is where I am trying to provide the logic to be able to filter by different fields.

```
// GET: PurchaseOrder
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search,  int? page)
{

    if (searchBy == "Requestor")
    {
        return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Requestor.ToUpper().Contains(search)).OrderBy(i => i.DateOrdered).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 15));
    }
    else if (searchBy == "Vendor")
    {
        return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Vendor.ToUpper().Contains(search)).OrderBy(i=>i.DateOrdered).ToPagedList(page??1,15));
    }
    else if (searchBy == "workOrder")
    {
        return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.PurchaseRequest_.ToUpper().Contains(search)).OrderBy(i => i.DateOrdered).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 15));
    }
    else if (searchBy == "dateSearchBegin")
    {
        return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Date > "dateSearchBegin" && x.Date < "dateSearchEnd").OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToPagedList(page ?? 1,15));
    }
    else if (searchBy == "dateSearchEnd")
    {
        return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Date > "dateOrderedBegin" && x.Date < "dateOrderedEnd").OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToPagedList(page ?? 1,15));
    }
    int pageSize = 15;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    pageNumber = page == null ? (ViewBag.pageData == null ? 1 : (int)ViewBag.pageData) : page.Value;
    ViewBag.pageData = page;
    return View(db.PurchaseOrders.OrderBy(i => i.DateOrdered).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

I am getting an error message  that states "operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'string'. How can I fix this error, and is there a more efficient way to code this to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: you are comparing ``DateTime`` object with ``string``

Comment: `x.Date > "dateSearchBegin"` you're comparing types `DateTime` and `string` which isn't valid or logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct `DateTime` object from query (`string search`) and then use it in linq query.

```
var dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(search)
var dtTo ...

return View(db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => x.Date > dtFrom && x.Date < dtTo).OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToPagedList(page ?? 1,15));
```

But you need also to introduce the ability to search by multiple properties at once. You can achieve this by only returning `IQueryable` from the linq queries and do subsequent queries on it. This way you can concatenate multiple queries:

```
var filtered = db.PurchaseOrders.Where(x => ...).AsQueryable(); 
filtered = filtered.Where(x => ...).AsQueryable();
```

etc

and then return

```
filtered.ToPagedList()
```

Comment: How do you set the textbox in the view equal to the dtFrom variable?

Comment: search is an empty string value

Comment: You can send the model to the view along with data, the model would contain all the fields for searching